# Python - how to write strings to file without quotes and spaces?

Tags: python, string, io

Is it possible to write into file string without quotes and spaces (spaces for any type in list)?

For example I have such list:

`['blabla', 10, 'something']`

How can I write into file so line in a file would become like:

`blabla,10,something`

Now every time I write it into file I get this:

`'blabla', 10, 'something'`

So then I need to replace `'` and `' '` with empty symbol. Maybe there is some trick, so I shouldn't need to replace it all the time?

Comment: How are you writing to file? This should only happen if you're using some auto-escaping thing like a csvwriter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work:

```
lst = ['blabla', 10, 'something']
# Open the file with a context manager
with open("/path/to/file", "a+") as myfile:
    # Convert all of the items in lst to strings (for str.join)
    lst = map(str, lst)  
    # Join the items together with commas                   
    line = ",".join(lst)
    # Write to the file
    myfile.write(line)
```

Output in file:

```
blabla,10,something
```

---

Note however that the above code can be simplified:

```
lst = ['blabla', 10, 'something']
with open("/path/to/file", "a+") as myfile:
    myfile.write(",".join(map(str, lst)))
```

Also, you may want to add a newline to the end of the line you write to the file:

```
myfile.write(",".join(map(str, lst))+"\n")
```

This will cause each subsequent write to the file to be placed on its own line.

Comment: Great code, but mine is all outputting on 1 line, despite including the +"\n"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like that ?

```
yourlist = ['blabla', 10, 'something']
open('yourfile', 'a+').write(', '.join([str(i) for i in yourlist]) + '\n')
```

Where

`', '.join(...)` take a list of strings and glue it with a string (`', '`)

and

`[str(i) for i in yourList]` converts your list into a list of string (in order to handle numbers)

Comment: you should close the file after opening it... i think is better with open(file) as f: etc .etc.

Comment: Since `open` go out of context just at the end of line (no variable to store file object), its destructor should automatically call the `close()` function. Well at least I think it should work that way... but you may be right, after all it depends on python's garbage collector

Comment: mmm I've tried but it doesn't work (there is an error in yourlist instead of yourList) and the .txt is separated with space

Answer (score 1):

Initialise an empty string j
for all item the the list,concatenate to j which create no space in for loop,
printing str(j) will remove the Quotes

```
  j=''
  for item in list:
       j = j + str(item)
  print str(j)
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.