# python write string to a file without quotes

Tags: python, string, file

I am trying to write some strings to a file but without quotes.

I am reading from a list and trying to write `item[0]` to an output file.

I tried to map and do `item[1:-1]` but none of them worked.

this my code:

```
for item in sorted(wrong_blocks):
      output.write(str(item[0]))
```

this keep writing to the file:

```
"word"
```

but I just want:

```
word
```

without quotes

I checked this 
[Python - how to write strings to file without quotes and spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585559/python-how-to-write-strings-to-file-without-quotes-and-spaces)

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. Is it just missing the parenthesis, or is there more stuff that got truncated?

Comment: now it is correct

Comment: Did you try `output.write(str(item[0])[1:-1])`?

Comment: yes still write with quotes

Comment: `output.write(str(item[0]).strip('"'))`?

Comment: Can we know the contents of `sorted(wrong_blocks)` ?

Comment: .strip('"')) it worked.

Comment: I do not understand, the problem are you trying to remove quotes from stings that contain quotes?

The following code works:
```python
my_strings = ["I ", "am ", "the ", "pied ", "piper"]
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as handle:
    for string in my_strings:
        handle.write(string)
```
There are no quotes in the file foo.txt.

Comment: can you TigerhawkT3 post it as the answer to mark it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all instances of a given set of characters from either side of a string with `str.strip`:

```
>>> s = '''"hello!"'''.strip('!"')
>>> print(s)
hello
```

Change your `output.write` call to `output.write(str(item[0]).strip('"'))` and it will remove any unwanted quotes.

Comment: His code seems right, but knowing the contents `wrong_blocks` would reveal the actual reason behind sam_com's question. But `.strip('"')` is no harm if you really don't need double quotes this case.